# Embedded database error : Why it is giving null result

Tags: spring-boot, junit, jdbctemplate, embedded-database

I am trying to write Junit test case for my repository class which has jdbctemplate using embedded database.

But when I am running the test method, the query is returning null. From logs I can see the in memory Database and insert queries were executed.

Can you point out what am I doing wrong.

User Repo -

```java
public class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryDao{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public List<UserDto> findAllUsers() {

        List<UserDto> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT EMPLOYEESURR,CISUSERLOGINID, CISUSERLASTLOGINDATE, INACTFLAG, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME " +
                        "FROM SECURITY.CISUSER ORDER BY LASTNAME", new RowMapper<UserDto>() {
                    @Override
                    public UserDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
                        UserDto user=new UserDto();
                        user.setEmployeesurr(rs.getInt("EMPLOYEESURR"));
                        user.setSid(rs.getString("CISUSERLOGINID"));
                        user.setCisUserLastLogonDate(rs.getDate("CISUSERLASTLOGINDATE"));
                        user.setStatus(rs.getString("INACTFLAG"));
                        user.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                        user.setLastName(rs.getString("LASTNAME"));

                        return user;
                    }
                }
        );

        return result;

    }

}
```

unit test class -

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("data/DDL_CREATE_HSQL_SCHEMA_CAMS_ADMIN.sql")
                .addScript("data/DDL_INSERT_HSQL_SCHEMA_CAMS_ADMIN.sql")
                .build();

                MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        userRepository = new UserRepository();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(jdbcTemplate, "dataSource", dataSource);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userRepository, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);

    }

    @Test
    public void findAllUsersSuccess(){

        try{

            List<UserDto> response = userRepository.findAllUsers();
            assertNotNull(response);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should there be a result? You are mocking things, creating thins. So I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Your test simply doesn't make any sense. Your inmemory database isn't being used. Also if auto wiring works you are using the spring configured `JdbcTemplate`. I strongly suggest a read of the testing chapter if the spring boot reference guide.

Comment: I want to cover the row mapping lines, thats why i want result. and how to use embedded db in jdbctemplate.

Comment: The embedded database IS a `DataSource`, you can simply inject that into the template. But why not just write a simple `@JdbcTest` and use an `@SQL` annotation to execute your sql. That is a lot simpler then your contraption.